# Granting permissions to Microsoft graph API on Enterprise Applications Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an application registered in Azure, API permissions set etc. However when I go into Enterprise applications >> permissions >> User consent. I cannot see where to add the following permissions

```
Microsoft graph >> User.Read
Microsoft graph >> openid
Microsoft graph >> profile
Microsoft graph >> offline_access
```

If one clicks on the button which says review permissions, you are presented with the following options, there is no option to add.

[image]

I have got another enterprise application which has the following permissions, what I am trying to do is duplicate the permissions for another app, see below.

[image]

Does anyone know how to add these permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

To Grant the permissions to Microsoft graph API on Enterprise Applications Azure you must have **`Global Administrator`** or **`Privileged Administrator`** role as mentioned in this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-user-consent?tabs=azure-portal#configure-user-consent-settings).

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:**

*Go to Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Enterprise applications -> Consent and permissions - > User consent settings*

[image]

[image]

**Please note that your users have to sign-in by consenting the form like below**:

[image]

**Once the users consent the form, permissions are added under user consent successfully like below:**

[image]

For more in detail, please **refer** below link:

[Enterprise Application Consent Requests in Azure : Jeff Schertz's Blog](http://blog.schertz.name/2020/04/enterprise-application-consent-requests-in-azure/)

**UPDATE:**

You can make use of below **`authorization endpoint`** that direct users to record consent.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/Your_TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=Your_Client_ID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=Your_Redirect_Uri
&response_mode=query  
&scope= Your_Scope
&state=12345
```

Please check this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/application-consent-experience#consent-and-permissions) to know more in detail.

Comment: Thanks for the message, I think this is likely to be what we are missing. In your earlier instruction, you have mentioned sign in, how do we get to the sign in so as to consent ?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: do i need to run a Ps script to call the endpoint. read the link pasted, I didnt see an example and was wondering.